# Creating a new column in a Pandas data frame from the index of a specific character in another column

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have a Pandas data frame that contains a column of emails:

```
Email
kitty@gmail.com
cat@yahoo.com
dog@aol.com
person@hrc.com
```

The data type of this column/Series is UNICODE, which appears to not work well for what I'm trying to do. What I'd like to get is a column of just the email domains in str format, something like this:

```
Domain
gmail.com
yahoo.com
aol.com
hrc.com
```

I have tried doing this:

`df['domain'] = df['Email'][:,df['Email'].find('@'):]`

but I get an attribute error: ''Series' object has no attribute 'find''.

I've searched all over Stack Overflow but have only found ways of selecting substrings based on a single chosen integer, but that doesn't work for this situation since the location of the '@' is different in each instance. I'd really like to avoid using a for loop to do this. Does anybody know of a simple way to accomplish this? I believe that the UNICODE data type might be interfering.

EDIT:
The solution provided by @rojeeer works great when I create sample data in a separate environment (iPython), but using it on a table in Databricks (Python 2.7.10), I continuously get errors:

```
TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_type'
TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the data in my table is encoded as Unicode (or unencoded). I’ve tried several things to convert it to str:

```
df[‘email’] = df[‘email’].map(lambda x: x.encode("utf-8"))
df[‘email’] = df[‘email’].encode("utf-8")
```

I’ve also tried to normalize the data by trying these approaches:

```
import unicodedata as ucd
df[‘email’] = ucd.normalize('NFKD', df[‘email’])

import unicodedata as ucd
df[‘email’] = ucd.normalize('NFKD', df[‘email’]).encode(‘ascii’,’ignore’)

import unicodedata as ucd

df[‘email’]= df[‘email’].map(lambda x: ucd.normalize('NFKD', x))
```

These continually return errors:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
TypeError: must be unicode, not None
```

How can I convert this series to str?

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas, `str` functions cannot be called directly, you need call it as `df.str.function`, see [Working with text](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

For you application, I think two functions could be your choice: [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract). The `str.split` for `Series` is very similar as `split` for `str` that split string by regular express delimiters. While the `str.extract` is more powerful to specify how to extract.

Here is a sample code:

```
In [16]: df['Email'].str.split('@', expand=True)
Out[16]: 
        0          1
0   kitty  gmail.com
1     cat  yahoo.com
2     dog    aol.com
3  person    hrc.com
```

Set `expand=True` will expand the `Series` to `DataFrame` contains as many columns as length of split results.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.